# chesspiece in list to announce winner

Tags: python

```
def destroy_piece(self, piece):
        """ Removes piece from the canvans and click-handler
            automatily called by move_piece
        """
        img1=piece.get_img_int(0)
        img2=piece.get_img_int(1)
        
        del self._on_clicks[str(img1)]
        del self._on_clicks[str(img2)]
        
        self.delete(piece.get_img_int(0))
        self.delete(piece.get_img_int(1))
        
        self.destroyed_pieces = []
        self.destroyed_pieces.append(piece)
        
        for elem in self.destroyed_pieces:
            if  ......
                messagebox.showinfo("WINNER")


               
class GUIKing(GUIChessPiece,King):
    def __init__(self,board,row,col,color,path="./imagepack/"):
        
        if color==BLACK:
            path1=path+"bk.png"
            path2=path+"bk_s.png"
        else:
            path1=path+"wk.png"
            path2=path+"wk_s.png"
        
        GUIChessPiece.__init__(self,board,row,col,color,path1,path2)
    
    def on_click(self,event):
        GUIChessPiece.on_click(self,event)
```

I am having trouble with continuing this code to detect win, simply by checking if the king is in the list, pieces are classes represented by pictures on a canvas. Though is it the images or the piece that is getting appended to the list? I am attaching the code for the king class

Comment: I don't understand why you would check for a winner here, if this is conventional chess one doesn't win by destroying pieces.  Can you write out exactly what state of self.destroyed_pieces would lead you to print 'winner'?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to write that I want to check if the king is in the list

Comment: You can't destroy a king!  You are able to edit your question, but you should search for `python list in operator` and you'll find your answer. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-does-in-operator-work-on-list-in-Python#:~:text=Python's%20in%20operator%20lets%20you,equal%20to%20the%20given%20item.

Comment: Is there a `King` class or a `Piece` class with some `type` attribute?

Comment: There is a king class that is represented by an image

Comment: Will the image or the class append to the list

Answer (score 0):

Because 'King' is a class, then to identify whether a member of that class is in the list `self.destroyed_pieces` you can do:

```
for elem in self.destroyed_pieces:
    if  isintance(elem,King):
        messagebox.showinfo("WINNER")
```